# Importing data to SAS from text file with multiple delimiters and line breaks in character variables

Tags: sas

I want to read into SAS a text file data set that uses two different delimiters, "|" and the string "[end text]". It is arranged as below:

```
var1|var2|var3
4657|366|text that 
has some line 
breaks [end text]
45|264| more text that has
line breaks [end text]
```

I am trying to figure out how to recognize both of these these two delimiters. I tried to use the DLMSTR option, but this didn't work:

```
data new ;
  infile 'file.txt' dlmstr='|'||'[report_end]'  DSD firstobs=2 ;
  input var1 var2 var3 $;
run;
```

Is there any way to use these two delimiters at the same time? Or am I using the wrong input style to import my data?

Comment: Can you replace the "[End Text]" into 'I' delimiter in the txt file itself? And then read it as a normal file with single delimiter

Comment: I did not realize I could use find-and-replace in a plain text file! That should work, thanks for that very easy solution.

Comment: no worries !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS can read delimited files that have embedded line breaks as long as the embedded line breaks use different character than the normal end of line. So if your real observations end with CRLF (normal for a Windows text file) and the embedded line breaks are just single LF character then those extra breaks will be treated as just another character in that field.

```
var1|var2|var3<CR><LF>
4657|366|text that<LF> 
has some line<LF>
breaks [end text]<CR><LF>
45|264| more text that has<LF>
line breaks [end text]<CR><LF>
```

For example here is a data step that could convert your original file.

```
data _null_;
  infile original lrecl=32767 ;
  file copy lrecl=1000000 termstr=lf ;
  input ;
  _infile_ = tranwrd(_infile_,'[end text]','0d'x);
  if _n_=1 then _infile_=trim(_infile_)||'0d'x;
  len = length(_infile_);
  put _infile_ $varying32767. len  ;
run;
```

But it might be better to replace the embedded line breaks with some other character , like ^, instead.

```
data _null_;
  infile original truncover ;
  file copy lrecl=1000000 ;
  input line $char32767.;
  len = length(line);
  put line $varying32767. len @;
  if _n_=1 or index(_infile_,'[end text]') then put ;
  else put '^' @;
run;
```

Result:

```
var1|var2|var3
4657|366|text that^has some line^breaks [end text]
45|264| more text that has^line breaks [end text]
```

Which is easy to read.

```
Obs    var1    var2                      var3

 1     4657    366     text that^has some line^breaks [end text]
 2     45      264     more text that has^line breaks [end text]
```

Comment: I tried your second suggestion and it worked! Thank you